# jQuery Mobile, REquire JS and Backbone REST Collection example

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm really new in using Backbone, RequireJS methods combined with the jQuery Mobile. On the official demo page [JQuery with Backbone](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/backbone-requirejs/backbone-require.html) they are parsing just a sample json Array in the file CategoriesCollection.js. I would like to change this to the real world example using REST and I do not have a clue how to achieve this.

The CategoreCollection.js code follows:

```
// Category Collection
// ===================

// Includes file dependencies
define([
    "jquery",
    "backbone",
    "../models/CategoryModel" ], function( $, Backbone, CategoryModel ) {



    // Extends Backbone.Router
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {

        // The Collection constructor
        initialize: function( models, options ) {

            // Sets the type instance property (ie. animals)
            this.type = options.type;

        },

        // Sets the Collection model property to be a Category Model
        model: CategoryModel,

        // Sample JSON data that in a real app will most likely come from a REST web service
        jsonArray: [

            { "category": "animals", "type": "Pets" },

            { "category": "animals", "type": "Farm Animals" },

            { "category": "animals", "type": "Wild Animals" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Blue" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Green" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Orange" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Purple" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Red" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Yellow" },

            { "category": "colors", "type": "Violet" },

            { "category": "vehicles", "type": "Cars" },

            { "category": "vehicles", "type": "Planes" },

            { "category": "vehicles", "type": "Construction" }

        ],

        // Overriding the Backbone.sync method (the Backbone.fetch method calls the sync method when trying to fetch data)
        sync: function( method, model, options ) {

            // Local Variables
            // ===============

            // Instantiates an empty array
            var categories = [],

                // Stores the this context in the self variable
                self = this,

                // Creates a jQuery Deferred Object
                deferred = $.Deferred();

            // Uses a setTimeout to mimic a real world application that retrieves data asynchronously
            setTimeout( function() {

                // Filters the above sample JSON data to return an array of only the correct category type
                categories = _.filter( self.jsonArray, function( row ) {

                    return row.category === self.type;

                } );

                // Calls the options.success method and passes an array of objects (Internally saves these objects as models to the current collection)
                options.success( categories );

                // Triggers the custom `added` method (which the Category View listens for)
                self.trigger( "added" );

                // Resolves the deferred object (this triggers the changePage method inside of the Category Router)
                deferred.resolve();

            }, 1000);

            // Returns the deferred object
            return deferred;

        }

    } );

    // Returns the Model class
    return Collection;

} );
```

Comment: Please explain what "real world example" you wish to achieve.

Comment: This is example is not good, they are overriding sync to provide a local object - this is not a good way to do this, some googling for things like "mock api" or tools "mockjax" will reveal better ways. By nature Backbone works with live data, they have broken it by overriding sync. Any backbone tut on the topic of models will show you this. As for the ideal setup that is a tough question. I recommend my colleague's starter repo - https://github.com/mderrick/backbone-boilerplate. Also at the very least I would extend Views to support subviews and the extend method for multiple inheritance.

Comment: To change the jsonArray (in the code) to be the resource from the REST service, for example url (http:/example.com/api/users) or whatever. I just need to see how the logic goes within the Collection itself, because the Backbone tutorials do not have the samples which are combined with the RequireJS and jQuery Mobile. So, in short, in the example provided above, I just need to see how I could retrieve the JSON by REST.